# Como usar o newFragment.show()?

Tags: android, datepicker, dialog, fragment

Estou com problemas em exibir um calendário após clicar em um `button`. Não reconhece o `newFragment.show();`

```
public void secionarData(View view) {
    DialogFragment dialogo = new DatePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(this.getFragmentManager(),"Date Picker");
}
```

Já importei os seguintes pacotes e permanece o problema:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import java.util.Calendar;
```

Answer (score 0):

Consegui!

O código correto:

```
 public void secionarData(View view) {
        DialogFragment dialogo = new DatePickerFragment();
        dialogo.show(this.getFragmentManager(), "Date Picker");
    }
```